# Powershell problem, files from remote do local by powershell using RDB

Tags: powershell

I want to import files from remote PC to local PC. Im connecting by RDB - it works but my code cant find path to the folder....

\C:\Users\User\Desktop\kgkg - remote
\ndwarszawa01.pgn.corp\home$\adam.banas\Documents\raporty_KG - local

```
# dane
$ComputerName = "172.16.34.45"
$Username = "xxxxxx"
$Password = "xxxxxxxx"

# sciezka do aplikacji
$RDPPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Remote Desktop Connection.lnk"

# otwieranie aplikacji
Start-Process -FilePath $RDPPath

# czas na otwarcie apki
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# wysylanie danych
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$ComputerName")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")

# czekaj na drugie okno dialogowe
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# wysylanie danych
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Password")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")


# sciezki
$zdalnaŚcieżkaDoPliku = "\\172.16.34.45\AAT-KTSTD-7229\kgkg"
$lokalnaŚcieżkaDocelowa = "\\ndwarszawa01.pgn.corp\home$\adam.banas\Documents\raporty_KG"

# skopiuj plik i przenies
Copy-Item -Path $zdalnaŚcieżkaDoPliku -Destination $lokalnaŚcieżkaDocelowa -Force
```

I tried entering different paths, but none of them works.

also and this happen:

Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\172.16.34.45\AAT-KTSTD-7229\kgkg' because it does not exist.
At line:37 char:1

- Copy-Item -Path $zdalnaŚcieżkaDoPliku -Destination $lokalnaŚcieżkaDoc ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\172.16.34.45\AAT-KTSTD-7229\kgkg:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExc
  eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
  ```

how to determine corectlly path?

Comment: By RDB, do you mean RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol)?

Comment: Please consider translating the variable names and references to English to increase the readability of your code sample.

Comment: Of course you know it is a bad practice to store passwords in clear text. Especially with-in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the profile of a user using the network (in a UNC-path) you has to use an existing share in the path.

So if there's a profile for `User1` on `Server1` the `UNC-path` would be
`\\Server1\c$\users\User1`

The adminstrative share of C:\ (`c$`) is only available for administrators.